# QML Listview space items to fill width

Tags: qt, listview, qml, spacing

I have a ListView (horizontal orientation) in my qml containing some fixed-size elements. I want items to be spaced out to fill the entiew width of ListView element. So if there are less elements I want them to be spaced out more. Basically what I need is exactly like `Layout.fillWidth = true` property of RowLayout but for ListView.

I can count how many items I have, then subtract total items width from ListView width, divide by items count and assign the spacing but it seems too silly to do.
Is there a way to do this automatically like in RowLayout?

[image]

Or maybe I need to use something different from ListView for this? Something like RowLayout but that I can assign my list data model to?

Comment: With ListView you get [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#listview-layouts). `RowLayout` with `Repeater` might get you close to or exactly what you want. Be careful with the number of elements though.

Comment: @scopchanov thanks I'll take a look at Repeaters

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you want with a `ListView`, you just need to adjust the spacing dynamically based on how many delegates you have. This example will break down if your delegates are differently-sized (as this is based only on the width of the first delegate), or if the delegates cumulatively exceed the width of the `ListView`.

```
ListView {
    width: 500
    orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    model: 6
    spacing: {
        if (count > 0) {
            return (width - (itemAtIndex(0).width * count))/(count - 1)
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    delegate: Rectangle {
        implicitHeight: 50
        implicitWidth: 50
        color: "red"
        border.width: 1
    }
}
```

[image: 6 delegates]
[image: 4 delegates]

`ListView` may not be the most appropriate container for this task. I say this because it has a built in `ScrollView` and other behaviors that it sounds like you don't need. If all you need is a simple row of a few identically-sized delegates, I agree with scopchanov and believe that a `Repeater` inside a `RowLayout` would be the best option. Here is a simple example:

```
RowLayout {
    width: 500

    Repeater {
        model: 6
        delegate: Rectangle {
            implicitHeight: 50
            implicitWidth: 50
            color: "tomato"
            border.width: 1
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter // must be set to align the rectangles within their empty space
        }
    }
}
```

[image: 6 delegates]
[image: 4 delegates]

You may notice that this introduces gaps to the left and right, if these gaps are unacceptable, you may need to set the `spacing` on the `RowLayout` in the same manner as the `ListView` example instead.